GitHub actions for my project
I've come up with the following actions for my project. These came up by reading the relevant documentation and it's my first try at creating a proper workflow for managing my project.
Are there any optimizations, or more "standard" ways of doing things? Additionally I found some popular actions for e.g. creating tags, or managing the changelog, but I'm not sure if they are the best.
build.yml
name: build-linux

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref_name == 'main'
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - uses: cachix/install-nix-action@v27
      with:
        extra_nix_config: |
          access-tokens = github.com=${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}

    - name: Build
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}
      run: nix build
      env:
        NIX_CONFIG: "access-tokens = github.com=${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}"

release.yml
name: Create Release

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:  # Allows manual triggering
    inputs:
      bump_type:
        description: 'Version bump type (major, minor, patch)'
        required: true
        default: 'patch'
        type: choice
        options:
          - patch
          - minor
          - major

permissions:
  contents: write
  packages: read

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Bump version and push tag
        id: tag_version
        uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v6.2
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          default_bump: ${{ inputs.bump_type }}

      - uses: cachix/install-nix-action@v27
        with:
          extra_nix_config: |
            access-tokens = github.com=${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}

      - name: Run Release Workflow Preset
        run: cmake --workflow --preset release

      - name: Create Release
        if: steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag }}
          name: Release ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag }}
          body: ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.changelog }}
          files: |
            build/package/*.tar.gz

update-changelog.yml
name: "Update Changelog"

on:
  release:
    types: [released]

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.release.target_commitish }}

      - name: Update Changelog
        uses: stefanzweifel/changelog-updater-action@v1
        with:
          latest-version: ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
          release-notes: ${{ github.event.release.body }}

      - name: Commit updated CHANGELOG
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
        with:
          branch: ${{ github.event.release.target_commitish }}
          commit_message: Update CHANGELOG
          file_pattern: CHANGELOG.md

